# Rust MAMP PRO mysql connection

Tags: mysql, rust, mamp-pro

I am trying to connect to my MAMP PRO database but I getting `Connection refused (os error 61)`
all the time.

Here is my code and my env file:

**Rust**

```rust
use mysql::*;
use mysql::prelude::*;

pub struct DB {
    connection: PooledConn
}

struct Test {
    name: String,
    last_name: String
}
#[allow(dead_code)]
impl DB {
    pub fn new<'a>(host: &'a str, user: &'a str, name: &'a str, pass: &'a str) -> Self {
        let url = format!("mysql://{}:{}@{}/{}?prefer_socket=false", user, pass, host, name);
        println!("{}", url);
        let pool = Pool::new(url.as_str()).unwrap();
        
        Self { 
            connection: pool.get_conn().unwrap() 
        }
    }

    pub fn test(&mut self) -> std::result::Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
        let tests = vec![
            Test {name: String::from("test1"), last_name: String::from("test2")}
        ];
        self.connection.exec_batch(
            r"INSERT INTO test (name, last_name)
              VALUES ( :name, :last_name)",
              tests.iter().map(|test| params! {
                "name" => &test.name,
                "last_name" => &test.last_name,
            })
        )?;

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

**Env**

```bash
SERVER_IP="127.0.0.1:1337"

DB_HOST="127.0.0.1:3306"
DB_USER="api_host"
DB_NAME="api_host"
DB_PASSWORD="12345678admin"
```

Also here some additional images:

**MySQL Top bar**
[image]

**Port settings**
[image]

I already tried 8889 port and localhost instead of 127.0.0.1.
Remanaged user with database.
Don't know to pass socket.
Would appreciate any suggestions, thanks in advance.

Comment: You should isolate the problem to the client-side or the server-side. Does the `mysql` CLI connect when ran from the same environment as the Rust code?

Comment: Sorry for late answer, but it's seems to be server-side issue. I tried it with php (laravel) which I used for many projects with mamp pro db.

Comment: @kmdreko - well I just fixed it in laravel by defining mysql socket, tho I don't know how I should do it in rust. I will check documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've finally resolved the issue. First of all, I'd like to thank [kmdreko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189130/kmdreko) for their assistance. Their question helped to clarify the problem - the socket.

So, if someone else encounters this issue, here's how I resolved it:

**Here is my DB constructor**

```rust
 pub fn new<'a>(host: &'a str, user: &'a str, name: &'a str, pass: &'a str, socket: Option<&str>) -> Self {
        let builder = (|| -> OptsBuilder {
            let this = OptsBuilder::new()
                .ip_or_hostname(Some(host)) // Specify the socket path here
                .user(Some(user))
                .pass(Some(pass))
                .db_name(Some(name));

            match socket {
                Some(socket) => this.socket(Some(socket)),
                _ => this
            }
        })();
    
        let opts = Opts::from(builder);
        let pool = Pool::new(opts).unwrap();
        
        Self { 
            connection: pool.get_conn().unwrap() 
        }
    }
```

**And here is my .env**

```bash
SERVER_IP="127.0.0.1:1337"

DB_HOST="127.0.0.1:3306"
DB_USER="api"
DB_NAME="api"
DB_PASSWORD="api"
DB_SOCKET="/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock"
```